# Hibernate 5: Unknown entity, errorType: org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: hibernate, java-8, aws-lambda, hibernate.cfg.xml

We have a code originally cloned from https://github.com/arun-gupta/lambda-rds-mysql. Made changes to work with PostgreSQL RDS. When we run this code on AWS it gives the following error

**Error Message**

```
 {
      "errorMessage": "Unknown entity: org.sample.serverless.aws.rds.Employee",
      "errorType": "org.hibernate.MappingException",
      "stackTrace": [
        "org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:620)",
        "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1639)",
        "org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:108)",
        "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)",
        "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)",
        "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)",
        "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)",
        "org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)",
        "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:694)",
        "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:686)",
        "org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:681)",
        "org.sample.serverless.aws.rds.EmployeeHandler.handleRequest(EmployeeHandler.java:21)",
        "org.sample.serverless.aws.rds.EmployeeHandler.handleRequest(EmployeeHandler.java:11)"
      ]
    }
```

Below are the code files, can you please help us understand why we are receiving this error:

**Employee handler**

```
public class EmployeeHandler implements RequestHandler<Request, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setId(request.id);
            employee.setName(request.name);
            session.save(employee);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        return String.format("Added %s %s.", request.id, request.name);
    }
}
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (null != sessionFactory)
        return sessionFactory;

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://"
            + System.getenv("RDS_HOSTNAME")
            + "/"
            + System.getenv("RDS_DB_NAME");

    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", jdbcUrl);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", System.getenv("RDS_USERNAME"));
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", System.getenv("RDS_PASSWORD"));

    configuration.configure();
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    try {
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

**Employee Entity**

```
package org.sample.serverless.aws.rds;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + '}';
    }
}
```

**Hibernate CFG XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <mapping class="org.sample.serverless.aws.rds.Employee"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HibernateUtil class add the following line (before `configuration.configure();`).

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
```

Comment: Hi, this kind of moves to next stage. In my postgres I have tables in public schema when hibernate executes this is framing a query like below

`Hibernate: insert into Employee (name, id) values (?, ?)` when executed like this throws an error saying `ERROR: ERROR: relation "employee" does not exist`

When like below executes can you please help me understand why should we supplement schema. Is that a mandate or is there a better alternative for this
`INSERT INTO public."Employee"(id, name) VALUES (4, 1); `

Comment: I cloned the same project as you did, and adding this line make it works, I don't know why is not considering the information `<mapping class="---">`mentionned in hibernate-cfg.xml

Comment: add this property in hibernate-cfg.xml <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> the schema is not created yet. Or you can use "update" instead because "create" will remove the existing schema everytime you run the server

Comment: That works thank you not sure why it's not picking `<mapping class="org.sample.serverless.aws.rds.Employee" />` from hibernate.cfg.xml. Is there something you see with the Util class during the Service registry??

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and worked:

```
/*
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build()
*/
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).configure().build();

    try {
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }
```

[Source](https://coderanch.com/t/654369/databases/Hibernate-Mapping-hibernate-cfg-xml)